# como crear un id incremental en una funcion en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bootstrap

tengo una vista que me manda a traer un evento y dentro de ese evento hay varios precios asociados a el, en una lista desplegable al seleccionar uno quiero que el valor de ese id se pase a un botón actualmente lo tengo asi y de esa manera si me funciona pero solo en la primera iteración de mi foreach me pasa el id a mis botones pero en la segunda iteracion ya no me sirve el botón ya que no se le pasa ningun id pero no sabría como pasarselo

```
    <div class="form-group row" >
  <div class="col-sm-10">
<select class="form-control"  id="twek" onchange="fun()">
    <option selected value="" >Selecciona el precio a pagar</option>
     @foreach($content as $contenido)
    <option value="{{ url('/pagar/'.$contenido->precios_id) }}"> {{ $contenido->descripcion }} ${{ number_format($contenido->preciomx, 2) }} MXN / ${{ number_format($contenido->preciousd, 2) }} USD (Vigente al {{ $contenido->vigencia_fin }})</option>
    @endforeach

        </select>
<!--<p id="prueba"></p>-->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <a class="btn btn-info" href="" id="prueba"> <p>Pagar</p> </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function fun(){
    var twekers = document.getElementById('twek').value;
    document.getElementById("prueba").href= ""+twekers;
    //document.getElementById("tuto").innerHTML = "tu estas seleccionando: " + twekers;
  }
</script>
```

mi idea es que quizas el id del select debe ser incremental pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Puedes crear una variable de incremento fuera del ciclo, algo asi como `$i = 1` luego quemas esa variable junto al ID dentro de tu ciclo (por ej `id="twek<?php echo $i ?>"`), y al final dentro del ciclo, podrías hacer el incremento `$i++`

Comment: Cuál segunda iteración? Sólo veo 1.

Comment: @JesúsFranco creo que se refiere a la primer vuelta